# How to get Stream from an array of array of String?

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array, java-8, java-stream

I have following statement creating an array of array of String:

```
String[][] strArr = {{"Jazz","80"},{"sam","90"},{"shaam","80"},{"aditya","100"}};
```

Would it be possible to get stream as following? I tried it in Eclipse but got an error.

```
Stream<String,String> streamObj = Arrays.stream(strArr);
```

Tried to search on net but mostly results were showing to get stream from 1-D array of strings as shown below:

```
String[] stringArr = {"a","b","c","d"};
Stream<String> str = Arrays.stream(stringArr);
```

Comment: `Arrays.stream(strArr).flatMap(Arrays::stream)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no feasible representation such as `Stream<String, String>` with the `java.util.stream.Stream` class since the generic implementation for it relies on a single type such as it declared to be:

```
public interface Stream<T> ...
```

You might still `collect` the mapping in your sub-arrays as a key-value pair in a `Map<String, String>` as:

```
Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(strArr)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));
```

To wrap just the entries further without collecting them to a `Map`, you can create a `Stream` of `SimpleEntry` as :

```
Stream<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>> entryStream = Arrays.stream(strArr)
        .map(sub -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(sub[0], sub[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a POJO called StringPair and map the stream.

```
public class PairStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] strArr = {{"Jazz","80"},{"sam","90"},{"shaam","80"},{"aditya","100"}};
        Arrays.stream( strArr ).map( arr -> new StringPair(arr) ).forEach( pair -> System.out.println(pair) );
    }

    private static class StringPair {
        private final String first;
        private final String second;

        public StringPair(String[] array) {
            this.first = array[0];
            this.second = array[1];
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "StringPair [first=" + first + ", second=" + second + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

As well as you can use [Apache Commons lang Pair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html)

```
public class PairStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] strArr = {{"Jazz","80"},{"sam","90"},{"shaam","80"},{"aditya","100"}};
        Arrays.stream( strArr ).map( arr -> Pair.of(arr[0],arr[1]) ).forEach( pair -> System.out.println(pair) );
    }


}
```